How to get the object from disassembler code in 64-bit app?
I have the pattern that will find the bytes sequence in memory area.
0x74, 0x26, 0x48, 0x8B, 0x05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x48, 0x8D, 0x0D, 0, 0, 0, 0

Where's 0 - it can be filled by any byte.
It works fine.
Basically these bytes give me
.text:000000014002AD99 74 26     jz  short loc_14002ADC1

.text:000000014002AD9B 48 8B 05 86 D1 64 01      mov  rax, qword_141677F28

The question is how can I get qword_141677F28 from 14002AD99 address?
In 32-bit app I was able to do something like that:
000000014002AD9B + 2. And then I got the address that I needed, but in x64 bit it works a little bit different way. I don't get the correct result and instead of qword_14167777F28 I get a completely wrong result.
In memory the address after qword_ is correct. It gives me what I wanted, but what should I do?
Do I need to parse asm code or there's some another method to get qword_141677F28?
DWORD WINAPI thread(_In_ LPVOID core)
{
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stderr);

    std::vector<BYTE> pattern{ 0x74, 0x26, 0x48, 0x8B, 0x05, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x48, 0x8D, 0x0D, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    
    uintptr_t* address = get_address<uintptr_t*>(pattern, "xrEngine.exe");
    
    std::cout << std::hex << address + 5; // wrong result
    
    std::cin.get();
    
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(static_cast<HMODULE>(core), 0);

}```


So you want to know how the CPU understands which address to jump to when it sees a JZ SHORT instruction?

there are no such things as 64x or 32x bit app

You need to read the 4 byte displacement at offset 5 then add the base address and the length of the two instructions: 14002AD99 + 164D186 + 2 + 7 = 141677F28
Something like this:
int32_t disp = *(int32_t*)((uint8_t*)address + 5);
std::cout << std::hex << (uint64_t)address + disp + 2 + 7;


Bro, you're the legend. Thank you <3
